# How to set the metadata property when uploading a file to cloud storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm resizing a file with cloud functions and uploading the file to Firebase functions. I want to set the `content-type` to. image/jpeg. I'm using google cloud storage to return a bucket..

`const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket)`;

and when I upload the file..

```
bucket.upload(imgPath, {
                destination: join(bucketDir, newImgName),
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
                        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
                    }
                }

            });
```

I able to access the file type of the image uploaded to Firebase Storage, which is `application/octet-stream`, which triggers the operation. This is also the content-type of the resized file. How can I set the content-type to 'image/jpeg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [UploadOptions](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#UploadOptions) object passed as the second parameter is too deeply nested.  You only use the inner `metadata` property for custom metadata.  You can set `contentType` at the top level, according to the linked documentation.

```
bucket.upload(imgPath, {
    destination: join(bucketDir, newImgName),
    metadata: {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    }
});
```

I don't know what `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` is, so I left it off.  It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#request_properties_JSON).  If you're trying to set that as custom metadata, then do use the nested metadata property.

Comment: Thanks! this helped me set `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens`